# Paralax scroll of slider is not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with my parallax slideshow script. It's not scrolling smooth and its shaking weird. The thing is that I couldn't find the proper script for element(like slider etc), most of them are only for single image. There is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ypos,image;
function parallex () {
    ypos = window.pageYOffset;
    image = document.getElementById('slider');
    image.style.top = ypos * .8 +'px';
}
window.addEventListener('scroll',parallex);
```

link to the site: http://www.pappu-lighting.com/Slider/Home.html

Comment: That could be graphic software problem. You can step through numbers in your javascript function so that it appears smooth.

Comment: You can apply an easing function to the transition to make it feel "smoother".  There's no need to use jQuery for this but I'm linking to their docs because they provide a good description of [easings](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) and [animation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).  Other JS libraries exist with similar capabilities as well.

Comment: I'm not good with javascript/jquery at all. Can you tell me how to add this easing function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 600 && $(document).scrollTop() < 2500){
         var temp =  100 - ($(document).scrollTop() - 1200) / 8;
         var bonus = '50% ' + temp*-1 + '%';
         document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundPosition = bonus;
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the cone with this one with the proper ID, but it did nothing. The parallax effect disappeared.